# Add autolayout in storyboard and then update it programmatically

Tags: swift, autolayout

I have three buttons and I have added autolayout to all buttons. Between button1 and button2 there is a **constant of 15** and the same between button2 and button3. Check the red arrows.

What I would like to do is when I press button2 I want to increase the constant between button2 and button3 to **60** instead of **15** programmatically.

So before I click the button the view looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52cZl.png) and after I click the button, the view shall look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8nHQ.png).

Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: So you have added the constraints from code? Or do you have the constraints from IB? If from code, show us your sample, please.

Comment: Thought the title were clear but from IB, but it´s solved now thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by this way. You drag and drop constraint to the view controller as property. Same like this:

[image]

Now you hold reference to this constraint (I have name it like this `@IBOutlet weak var constraintSpaceButton2And3: NSLayoutConstraint!`). When you tap to button. You will change it:

```
self.constraintSpaceButton2And3.constant = 60
```

Hope this help!